# Flutter - Issues when I try to filter the results (using SearchDelegate)

Tags: flutter, search, filter

I got some problems to filter the results into the SearchDelegate.

Here is my code:

```
class CustomSearchDelegate extends SearchDelegate<String> {

  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _listaItensDropCategorias;
  List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> _listaItensDropEstados;


  String _itemSelecionadoCategoria;
  String _itemSelecionadoEstado;

  _carregarItensDropdown(){

    //Categorias
    _listaItensDropCategorias = Configuracoes.getCategorias();

    //Estados
    _listaItensDropEstados = Configuracoes.getEstados();

  }



  _abrirDialog(BuildContext context) async {

    _carregarItensDropdown();
    return showDialog(

        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context,StateSetter setState){

              return AlertDialog(

                content: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 20),
                      child: Text("Filtrar", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 27),),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Categoria", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20),),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Wrap(
                              alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                DropdownButton(
                                  value: _itemSelecionadoCategoria,
                                  items: _listaItensDropCategorias,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      color: Colors.black
                                  ),
                                  onChanged: (categoria){
                                    setState(() {
                                      _itemSelecionadoCategoria = categoria;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text("Estado", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 20),),
                          Expanded(
                            child: Wrap(
                              alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                DropdownButton(
                                  value: _itemSelecionadoEstado,
                                  items: _listaItensDropEstados,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      color: Colors.black
                                  ),
                                  onChanged: (estado){
                                    setState(() {
                                      _itemSelecionadoEstado = estado;
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Wrap(
                              alignment: WrapAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 30),

                                  child: GestureDetector(

                                    child: Text(
                                      "Aplicar",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue),
                                    ),

                                    onTap: (){ //************************************Here is my problem
                                      showResults(context);
                                      Navigator.pop(context);

                                    },

                                  ),

                                ),
                                GestureDetector(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Cancelar",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.lightBlue),
                                  ),
                                  onTap: (){
                                    Navigator.pop(context);
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],),
              );
            },
          );
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Widget> buildActions(BuildContext context) {
    return [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.clear),
        onPressed: () {
          query = "";
        },
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.tune),
        onPressed: () {
         _abrirDialog(context);
        },
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget buildLeading(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
      onPressed: () {
        close(context, "");
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
      return Pesquisar(query.toUpperCase(),_itemSelecionadoCategoria,_itemSelecionadoEstado);
  }
   

  }
```

As you can see, I build an "alertDialog" where the user can choose the filters (Categoria and Estado), and I put a GestureDetector "Aplicar" (see the image below) to apply automatically the filters and show results, but nothing happens when I press it.

[image]

But when I select the filters, type in the Search Field (see the image below) and press the search button (magnifying glass), the filters are applied.

[image]

P.S.: I know why it works when I press the search button, 'cause I passed the parameters ("_itemSelecionadoCategoria" , "_itemSelecionadoEstado") to the buildResults, where it answer when the search button is pressed.

So, my doubt is: What can I put in the onTap from GestureDetector "Aplicar" to give me the results with the filters applied? (I thought that putting "showResults(context)" in the "onTap" would solve my problem, but it didn't work).

Comment: Hello there, did you find the solution for this? I am facing the same issue.